# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

What is wrong with the code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session() as ses:
    c = tf.add(1, 2)
    d = ses.run(c)
    print(d)
```

Returns the error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\My
>   Files\Programs\Python\Tensorflow.py", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 63, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav
>   Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\framework_lib.py",
>   line 75, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav
>   Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.framework import errors   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav
>   Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.framework import errors_impl as _impl   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav
>   Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.util import compat   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py",
>   line 130, in 
>       remove_undocumented(**name**, _allowed_symbols)   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav
>   Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\all_util.py",
>   line 103, in remove_undocumented
>       should_have = make_all(module_name, doc_string_modules)   File "C:\Users\Vaibhav
>   Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\all_util.py",
>   line 55, in make_all
>       for m in _reference_pattern.finditer(doc_module.**doc**) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: There is nothing wrong code. It's giving me the result in my PC (ubuntu 14.04). This must be the issue of your system environment.

Just try `import tensorflow` alone, it will give you more idea about the problem.

Comment: Giving the same error! Akhilesh.

Comment: Try changing the name of your script. It is currently `Tensorflow.py` which could cause problems.

Comment: Not worked! Juanpa.

Comment: I don't know much about other system than ubuntu. You can refer to [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-3-error-on-import-mac/25779/3) link. It may help you to get some idea.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006320/tensorflow-pip-installation-issue-cannot-import-name-descriptor) also.

Comment: I'm also having this error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm also having this error on ubuntu 16, cuda 9.1, cudnn 7.0.5